# Lua script to control PC RGB lighting

Tags: lua, rgb

I have a MSI motherboard (B450 Tomahawk Max) and I, along with several other people, absolutely hate MSI's software suite because it does everything instead of doing the work it's intended to do.

I wanted to control the RGB LEDs present on my motherboard while staying away from MSI's software so I downloaded MSIRGB from github which uses lua scripts to control the pattern of the led lighting "animation".

The thing is I have no clue how to work with lua and work has been keeping me busy. The script below is a bundled script which smoothly transitions between all the colors.

```
-- Adapted from nagisa/msi-rgb's Hue Wheel effect

-- Variables
local saturation = 0.933
local value = 1.0

local delay = 80 -- delay between each colour update, in milliseconds
local colour_step = 1.1

--
Lighting.SetStepDuration(511)
Lighting.SetFlashingSpeed(0)
Lighting.SetBreathingModeEnabled(false)

local i = 0
while true do
    local r, g, b = Lighting.ColourUtils.HSVtoRGB((i % 98.0) / 98.0, saturation, value)

    r = tonumber(("%x"):format(r * 15), 16)
    g = tonumber(("%x"):format(g * 15), 16)
    b = tonumber(("%x"):format(b * 15), 16)

    Lighting.BatchBegin()
    for i = 1, 8 do
        Lighting.SetColour(i, r, g, b)
    end
    Lighting.BatchEnd()

    os.sleep(delay)

    i = i + colour_step
end
```

My request is a similar script that only cycles between the colors made from red and blue as the green leds don't work and I'm not able to send my motherboard for RMA because of my country's lockdown.

I know this is a doubt clearing/guidance website and not a request one but I will greatly appreciate any help.

Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
local r, g, b = Lighting.ColourUtils.HSVtoRGB((i % 98.0) / 98.0, saturation, value)
```

with

```
local j = i % 64
j = math.min(j, 64 - j)
local r, g, b = 1 - math.min(16, j)/16, 1, 1 - math.min(16, 32 - j)/16
```

Comment: Thank you for replying to my post. I did exactly as you asked me but the lights now only do colors that are made from green (the LEDs in my fans work but not on my motherboard which is how I'm able to carry out this observation) which is exactly the opposite to what I requested (colors that are made using only the reds and the blues). Nonetheless, thank you again and if you could help me solve this I'll be very grateful. I apologize if my English is not good enough for you to understand, it's not my first language.

Comment: @Liam - What colors do you see for the following calls: `Lighting.SetColour(i, 0, 0, 15)` `Lighting.SetColour(i, 0, 15, 0)`  `Lighting.SetColour(i, 15, 0, 0)` `Lighting.SetColour(i, 15, 0, 15)` ?

Comment: I don't know if my code is correct or not but I'm including it for you to see. 
`Lighting.SetFlashingSpeed(0)
Lighting.SetBreathingModeEnabled(true)

for i = 1, 8 do
    Lighting.SetColour(i, 15, 0, 15)
end`    The colors are in the order of your comment 1)Mix between green and yellow 2)Purple 3) Teal (mix between blue and green) 4) Solid Green   0,15,15 gives red 15,15,0 gives blue and 15,15,15 turns the lights off.

Comment: @Liam - Ok, the colors are just inverted.   Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this its only cycle with 2 colors

```
local saturation = 0.833
local value = 1.0

local delay = 3000
local colour_step = 1000

--
Lighting.SetStepDuration(511)
Lighting.SetFlashingSpeed(0)
Lighting.SetBreathingModeEnabled(false)

local i = 0
while true do
    local r, g, b = Lighting.ColourUtils.HSVtoRGB((i % colour_step) / colour_step, saturation, value)

    
    if(g > 0) then 
        b = g
    end

    
    r = tonumber(("%x"):format(r * 8), 16)
    g = tonumber(("%x"):format(g * 0), 16)
    b = tonumber(("%x"):format(b * 8), 16)

    Lighting.BatchBegin()
    for i = 1, 8 do
        Lighting.SetColour(i, r, g, b)
    end
    Lighting.BatchEnd()

    if((i % 500) / 500 == 0) then os.sleep(delay) end
    

    i = i + 1
end
```